# Strongly convergent to zero in $L^2$ but $H^1$ norm not vanishing

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be some open, bounded, smooth subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm wondering whether it is possible for a sequence of functions $f_n:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ to be strongly convergent to zero in $L^2$ but have non vanishing (e.g. constant) $H^1$ norm $||f_n||_{H^1}^2:=||f_n||_{L^2}^2+||Df_n||_{L^2}^2$.

I can't come up with an example, but I don't see how to prove that the $H^1$ norm should vanish either. Any help would be welcome. Hints are even better than full solutions.

Comment: Take $\varphi \in C_c^\infty (B_1(0))$, consider $\varphi(\varepsilon x)$ and translate that to some point in $\Omega$. Calculate both norms (asymptotically with dependence on $\varepsilon$). This should give you an example.

Comment: I'll try that out. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I've tried, but after doing the change of variable in the integrals all I find is that the $L^2$ norm is $O(1)$ (because the $\varepsilon^{-n}$ term cancels with the volume of the ball) and the $L^2$ norm of $D\phi_n$ goes to zero (because after the chain rule a term $\varepsilon^2$ appears and it dominates the derivative, which is bounded). I'm still trying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @PhoemueX's answer will lead you to a general situation. It works, of course. But here let me provide you a quick and insight example on $R^1$.

Take $I=(0,1)$ and define $u_n$ in following way:

For each fixed $n$, we partition $I$ into $n$'s small subinterval with length $1/n$. Let's name those interval by $I^n_i:=(i/n,i+1/n)$ for $i=0,1,2,...,n-1$. That is, $I^n_1=(0,1/n)$, $I^n_2=(1/n,2/n)$ etc...

Now we define $u_n$. Here I am not going to write done the math formula for $u_n$ but will rather just describe it for you. I think it is better this way.

Anyhow, for fixed $n$, we take $I^n_1$ and we build a triangle on $I^n_1$ with length $1/n$ and hight $1/n$, do the same thing for every $I^n_i$. Hence, $u_n$ is just $n$ small triangles with length $1/n$ and hight $1/n$.

Clearly, $u_n\to 0$ in $L^2(0,1)$. But what is $\|u_n'\|_{L^2(0,1)}$? In each $I^n_i$ we have 
$$ \int_{I^n_i}u_n'^2dx=\frac{4}{n} $$
and hence 
$$ \int_{I}u_n'^2dx= 4 $$
and we have our result.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't spend more time with @PhoemueX's suggestion and this concrete example is more clear to me. A small remark: I think, that with your definition of the intervals, we need to take $i=0,..,n-1$. Then you mean "just $n$ small triangles" (not $n+1$) and the integral of the derivative over the whole interval is exactly $4$.

Comment: yea, you are right. sorry i was a bit sleepy before, today is holiday after all :)

Answer (score 1):

Another example. Let $\Omega=(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $f_n(x)=\sin(n\,\pi\,x)/n$. Then
$$
\|f_n\|_2\le\frac1n\to0\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$
On the other hand
$$
\|f'_n\|_2^2=\pi^2\int_0^1\cos^2(n\,\pi\,x)\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can take any orthonormal sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $H^1$. Then you have $f_n \rightharpoonup 0$, but $\|f_n\|_{H^1} = 1$. Using the compact embedding from $H^1$ to $L^2$, you have $f_n \to 0$ in $L^2$.

More generally, you can construct a counterexample by using any weakly but not strongly convergent sequence in $H^1$.

Comment: I was actually looking for a weakly but not strongly convergent sequence, just I hadn't realised at the time! It is now all so obvious... thanks.